# WCF service username/password authentication over HTTP without SSL

Tags: .net, wcf, security, authentication, https

I would like to protect a simple WCF service sending username and password from the client and using a CustomUserNamePasswordValidator. With every example I try on the Web I am stuck behind huge configurations and obscure errors, SSL, certificates, etc...

The most similar alternative (to let you understand better) would be to pass a "serviceUsername" and "servicePassword" parameter (maybe hashed) to each and every method of the service and perform authentication here, but I admit it's an ugly and dirty solution.

I don't mind encrypting credential, because it won't be a security critical service. I need only a basic form of protection.

Thank you!

Alessandro

Answer (score 6):

In order to use Username/password authentication with BasicHttpBinding you cannot achieve as WCF imposes a restriction of passing username/password in clear text over the channel.

In order to overcome this issue we have something called **[ClearUserNameBinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html)**. This binding allows you to pass username/password over the channel which is similar to BasicHttpBinding